# Define print format for custom datatype

Tags: haskell

For the exercise that I'm doing, I implemented a datatype that is similar to `Maybe`:

```
type Some a = a
data Optional a = Some a | None
```

And a function:

```
safeRoot :: Double -> Optional Double
safeRoot x =
  if x >= 0
    then Some (sqrt x)
  else None
```

However, if I try to run the function from ghci like this:

```
safeRoot 4
```

I get:

```
No instance for (Show (Optional Double))
  arising from a use of ‘print’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

So how can I define a print format for `Optional`?

Comment: You're aware that your type `Some` is unrelated to the data constructor `Some` defined as part of `Optional`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `deriving (Show)` on your data type:

```
data Optional a = Some a | None deriving (Show)
```

Also, your `Optional` type is basically the same as `Maybe`, which is what is used throughout most libraries.